# Subir archivos a tabla mysql y mostrar en datatables

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando la carga de archivos mediante el método de move_uploaded_file(); a una carpeta dentro de mi servidor, pero no logro llevar esos datos a una tabla mysql para poder después mostrar ese archivo en una datatables y esten con las acciones de descargar y eliminar.

```
<?php

$dir_subida = 'uploads/';
$fichero_subido = $dir_subida.$_FILES['fichero_usuario']['name'];

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichero_usuario']['tmp_name'], $fichero_subido)) {
    echo "El fichero es válido y se subió con éxito.\n";
} else {
    echo "¡Posible ataque de subida de ficheros!\n";
}

echo 'Más información de depuración:';
print_r($_FILES['fichero_usuario']['name']);

print "</pre>";


?>
```

y la carga de la tabla la realizo con este codigo:

```
<?php include_once('conexion.php');?>

<?php

$nombre_archivo = $_FILES[name];
$size = $_FILES[size];

$query= "INSERT INTO archivos (id,nombre_archivo,size) VALUES (NULL, '$nombre_archivo', '$size' ";
//echo $query;
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$query );
$filasafectadas=$conn->affected_rows;
if($filasafectadas>0){
    $arr = array('agregado' => 1);
}else{
    $arr = array('agregado' => 0);
}

echo $_FILES[name];


?>
```

Comment: Hola. ¿El campo id es autoincremental?

Comment: Asi es. No logro llegar el archivo a la base de datos .

Comment: Creo que el problema es que tratas de meter NULL en el campo id. Yo nunca lo incluyo en los querys de insersión cuando es incremental. Pruebalo así: **`$query= "INSERT INTO archivos (nombre_archivo,size) VALUES ( '$nombre_archivo', '$size' )";**`

Comment: Ah! adicionalmente si size es numérico debes quitarle las comillas simples a '$size' nota que te faltaba un paréntesis de cierre. Lo agregué en el comentario anterior